# GS026: I sign the correct `safeTxHash` but `checkNSignatures` fails

Tags: etherscan, gnosis-safe

I want to be able to call `execTransaction` without gnosis infra (as a recovery measure), so I made a little signer web3.js app that takes all the parameters, hashes them exactly the way the safe contract does it in `encodeTransactionData`, this produces `safeTxHash`. I checked it against previous transactions I made through the Safe web UI, it matches.

I then use `personal_sign` to prompt the user to sign the hash.

```
                    const sign = await ethereum.request({
                        method: 'personal_sign',
                        params: [safeTxHash, from, 'Random text'],
                    });
```

We can then send around the signatures with my colleagues in email and once we have enough signatures, we can call `execTransaction` in eg. etherscan to interact with the safe without Gnosis servers.

However, calling `execTransaction` fails with GS026 (which means some of the signatures are bad). OK maybe I got the nonce wrong, or something, so let's try calling `checkNSignatures` directly to see which signature is bad. It turns out all of them are. Here's an example.

```
address: 0x360048390d7D967Bc634e1253fB9632290130ED7
data: 0x1901f575497ea4aae42517ffea2ac3cee51f6af01be4288b09746385e7ca8edb21900e9a43707f7f38353cc9a99de2dd46c6b41d91d425c2727e90d914785190cb7b
data hash: 0x3db1b18173909221b28b2a497995a26baef0712558a83f2755fda3799fbe93b0
signature: 0x1f48e4661e3adbb06c60c31291aa38265565ad72d87079bc07ce96cf9cbffabb7c5edefa071c108f9737930dad8085a33d0d5127c3fb8ddebc0be44c057c23711b
```

What drives me insane is that this is a transaction we've already signed and executed through the Safe Desktop app, and the signature matches the one that [we see on the blockchain in the successful](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf8a87e1b38ae5adeae6c304b28eded3b1b3a6537d188800bf2a2070c674856f1) `execTransaction` call!!

[image: etherscan screenshot showing signature matching the one above]

Sooo... what's wrong with my signature?

Comment: BTW you don't need to port the safe tx hashing code from solidity to javascript: you can just call `getTransactionHash` on the contract. Just sign that and you're fine

Answer (score 2):

Well, the last byte is wrong. The signature consists of three parts, `r`, `s` and `v`, where `v` is a single byte signifying the version. In the above example in the one generated by the web3.js app, it's `v == 0x1b` which is `27`. On the blockchain (in the transaction generated by Gnosis infra), the version is `0x1f`, which is `31`.

So clearly, you need to add four (4) to the signature. Five shalt thou not count, neither count thou three, excepting that thou then proceed to four. Six is right out.

I've realised this while simulating and debugging the `checkNSignatures` call in Tenderly [(simu link)](https://dashboard.tenderly.co/techcapo/project/simulator/efe25c2b-cc63-4c76-b9f1-8f72e88cb291/debugger). There's a special case if `v > 30` where the contract subtracts 4 from the version and adds some boilerplate to the hash.

```
            } else if (v > 30) {
                // If v > 30 then default va (27,28) has been adjusted for eth_sign flow
                // To support eth_sign and similar we adjust v and hash the messageHash with the Ethereum message prefix before applying ecrecover
                currentOwner = ecrecover(keccak256(abi.encodePacked("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32", dataHash)), v - 4, r, s);
            } else {
                // Default is the ecrecover flow with the provided data hash
                // Use ecrecover with the messageHash for EOA signatures
                currentOwner = ecrecover(dataHash, v, r, s);
            }
            require(currentOwner > lastOwner && owners[currentOwner] != address(0) && currentOwner != SENTINEL_OWNERS, "GS026");
```

If you are using `personal_sign`, instead `eth_sign`, it still seems like it appends the boilerplate under the hood. If you increment the signatures by 4 (`0x1b` -> `0x1f`), `checkNSignatures` and also `execTransaction` works like a charm [(simu link)](https://dashboard.tenderly.co/techcapo/project/simulator/70eb137c-a984-4b01-996f-4bd8f44562aa).

Comment: If the site allowed it, I'd give you 100 upvotes for the Python quote.